# Running a pre-built scenario like MoSTScenario with Flow

Tags: flow-project

I would like to train a single controlled agent in the MoSTScenario with flow, my problem is that I want the default configuration of the MoSTScenario not to be touched by flow. The thing is that I want to maintain all the configuration in the MoSTScenario(traffic lights functioning, car following models used by no-controlled agents,etc) and just include a vehicle controlled by me trained with RLlib. In flow tutorials the vehicle configuration used is the one defined by flow not the already existing in sumo, I do not know if there is someone there that has already done something like this and could help me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Alberto! This is a good question. However, we're moving to Slack for these discussions. Would you mind joining us at https://join.slack.com/t/flow-users/shared_invite/enQtNzk5NzE1OTkyNTE0LTU0YmE5ZTVkZmJmNDg1Nzg2YThjOThmY2ZlYWE2ZjQ0NTE1NjE3Y2YwMTljY2U5M2Y3MDhmMWUzZDM3YWViNmE and posting your question there?

Comment: This link is deprecated, can you please provide me an up to date one please.

Comment: My bad, here you go! https://join.slack.com/t/flow-users/shared_invite/enQtODQ0NDYxMTQyNDY2LTY1ZDVjZTljM2U0ODIxNTY5NTQ2MmUxMzYzNzc5NzU4ZTlmNGI2ZjFmNGU4YjVhNzE3NjcwZTBjNzIxYTg5ZmY